# Fisher information matrix of MLE's

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I know what it means to compute the fisher information matrix of a vector of parameters. However, how does one compute the fisher information matrix of a vector of MLE's?

Specifically, I am working with the Pareto distribution, which has density function
$$f_X(x)={\alpha k^\alpha \over x^{\alpha +1}},\mbox{     } \alpha,k>0  \mbox{ and } x>k.$$
After computing the MLE estimators $\hat{\alpha}$ of $\alpha$ and $\hat{k}$ of $k$, I was asked to compute the fisher information matrix of $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fisher information is essentially the negative of the expectation of the Hessian matrix, i.e. the matrix of second derivatives, of the log-likelihood. In particular, you have $$l(\alpha,k)=\log\alpha + \alpha \log k - (\alpha + 1) \log x$$ from which you compute the second-order derivatives to create a $2 \times 2$ matrix, which you take the expectation (and set $\alpha=\hat \alpha$ and $k=\hat k$).

Comment: Why must you take the inverse? In my course notes, it defines the fisher information matrix to be the negative of the hessian, after taking the expectation of the entries. However, my major issue is what specifically does it mean to find the information matrix of the MLE's? Do I merely substitute them in for $\alpha$ and $k$?

Comment: My apologies (error corrected), you should definitely take the expectation (element-wise), and do not take the inverse! (The inverse is the estimate for variance.)

And yes, the "information matrix for the MLEs", vaguely speaking, is simply the information matrix evaluated at the MLEs (think of it informally as a numerical measure for the information provided by the MLE)